# What is meant by a "non one time use EOA"

Tags: eoa

Could someone explain what is meant by a non-one-time-use externally owned account and what is used (or misused) for?

Comment: do you mean the kind of account in this article: https://link.medium.com/FzLKQlCPdZ? the account in this article is a one time address

Answer (score 1):

EOAs are user addresses i.e. not contracts. A "non one time use EOA" would be an address possessed by a user which is used multiple times rather than used and then discarded - such as MetaMask accounts. This is bad practice in terms of privacy, but good for tying a specific user to an address. Wherever you read that was probably referring to one or the other, I'd guess.